# Getting started with Play 2.0 -- Cannot find symbol: play.db.jpa.Model

Tags: java, playframework-2.0

I'm getting started with Play 2.0 by following along with the tutorial. I'm hitting an early roadblock though. When I try `play test`, I'm hitting a compiler error:

```
[error] /Users/spoletto/Desktop/historical/kleio/app/models/Student.java:9: cannot find symbol
[error] symbol  : class Model
[error] location: package play.db.jpa
[error] public class Student extends play.db.jpa.Model {
```

Likewise, in Eclipse, it's not finding the Model class (though it is finding the play.db.jpa package). I know I'm probably missing something really basic, but I'm stumped. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you need [play.db.ebean.Model](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/api/2.0/java/play/db/ebean/Model.html)

So I found checking the api docs for [Java](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/api/2.0/java/index.html) and [Scala](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/api/2.0/scala/index.html) really helpful with migrating to 2.0. A lot of the apis have changed and moved around. I always forget the links, but they are conveniently found at the [docs](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0/Home) *Browse APIs* button

Comment: Yep. Looks like the tutorial is just out of date. Thanks for steering me clear.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely because the relevant jars are not in your classpath.

try `play eclipsify` to generate a valid eclipse project.

How to setup your IDE: http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0/IDE

Comment: I did run ecipsify before importing the project. The jars are showing up under "Referenced Libraries" as I'd expect.

Comment: The error also occurs when running from the command line, independent of my Eclipse setup.

Comment: Perhaps mguymon's answer help.

Answer (score 0):

I got issues on latest with Play 2.6. Had to update `build.sbt` with

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  javaJdbc,
  guice,
  "org.postgresql" % "postgresql" % "9.3-1102-jdbc41"
)
```

And then in the class files re route imports on example code:

This import didn't work `import play.db.*;`

Switched to

```
import play.libs.concurrent.CustomExecutionContext;
import play.api.db.*;
```

Now it compiles. Hopefully I can figure out the rest ok